# Cannot retrieve ACF values from Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Custom Post Type called 'fotos' with a couple ACF fields connected to it.

Inside the while loop in my homepage i'm retrieving the most recent posts from this CPT. I want to show an ACF field called 'clients' for each of these posts. the $photo->ID is correctly returning the ID of the CPT post.

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- ... -->
  <?php
    $recent_photos = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => '8',
        'post_type' => 'fotos',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));
    if ($recent_photos):
        ?>

            <?php foreach ($recent_photos as $photo): ?>
                <div class="item-grid--item">
                    <?php the_field('client', $photo->ID); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<!-- ... -->
    <?php endwhile;
else:
    _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain');
endif;
?>
```

However, the_field, get_field, the_sub_field or get_sub_field return absolutely nothing. What could it possibly be? I checked everything and it's all correct!

Comment: Does the answer provided help or not? Are you saying that `$photo->id` does return the correct post id? It would seem that it shouldn't.

Comment: It did, I feel so stupid. I thought I tried `['ID']` before. Thank you for the help! I was losing my mind yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default return value type of **wp_get_recent_posts** is an associative array not object.

So you can change the return type of **wp_get_recent_posts**

```
$recent_photos = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => '8',
        'post_type' => 'fotos',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ), object);
```

or you can change the getting the ID in your default code.

```
<?php the_field('client', $photo['ID']); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I was going crazy over this yesterday and then the answer is so simple haha. Appreciate you!